# Reading answers from separate file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle, python-import

I am stuck with this code.
So, I am making an IRC bot which answers peoples questions. When a question is asked, I write it to a .txt file;

Main.py

```
Import os
Import hi
Question_file = 'question.txt'
Answer_file = 'answer.txt'

while True:

  Question = raw_input ("Question?").lower()

  with open(Question_file, "w") as q:
                   q.write(Question.lower())
                   q.close()

  with open(Answer_file, "r") as m:
    answer = m.read()

  if 'hi' in Question:
     print ("hi")

  else:
    print answer
```

Now that's all ok. Problem is with the hi.py

Hi.py

```
Import os
Import string
Question_file = 'question.txt'
Answer_file = 'answer.txt'


with open (Question_file, "r") as f:
  question = f.read()

  if "what year is it" in question:
     with open(Answer_file, "w") as r:
       r.write("2014")
  if "what month is it" in question:
     with open(Answer_file, "w") as r:
       r.write("July")
```

Problem is, Hi.Py won't write the correct answer? It just writes the answer to the first question and prints that answer every time a question is asked?

Comment: Those scripts shouldn't even run - Python is case-sensitive. Your indentation is screwed up. There are several other problems, but I don't think answering this makes any sense unless you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I get that maybe my indentation is not the best, that is why I have come for help.

Comment: "Not the best" is not the issue here. The scripts you have posted cannot even run due to lots of SyntaxErrors and one (obvious) IndentationError. You wouldn't get the behavior you're describing when running these scripts.

Comment: Leave me quickly test them. Sorry for this.

Comment: Also, why are you tagging the question Python 3.x and Python-idle?

Comment: I Edited it can you have a look?

Comment: Come on. `While true:` can't work, it has to be `while True:`. What are you doing?

Comment: It is the phone that does that. Not me

Comment: I have it all correct on my pc, spelling I mean

Comment: Then use your PC to post here. You're making it hard on yourself (and us).

Comment: I have no internet on my pc at the moment. i havr fixed the code to the best of my ability, can you please look now?

Comment: Does this code now make scence to you?

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
import hi
```

the file `hi.py` will be *executed* (once) and its objects made accessible to the importing program's namespace.

Let's look at what `hi.py` does:

```
with open (Question_file, "r") as f:   # Read entire file question.txt
  question = f.read()                  # into the variable "question"

  if "what year is it" in question:    # Look for this text;
     with open(Answer_file, "w") as r: # if found, *CREATE A NEW FILE* answers.txt
       r.write("2014")                 # and write "2014" to it.
  if "what month is it" in question:   # Same for the next text -
     with open(Answer_file, "w") as r: # if that's present, overwrite the file
       r.write("July")                 # with the text "July"
```

So you probably want to use `a` instead of `w`, so additional words will not overwrite the previous ones. You should also write some kind of separator (`\n`) into the file after each word, I guess.

Now let's look at what `main.py` does (*after* it has executed `hi.py` and done nothing with it):

```
while True:
  Question = raw_input ("Question?").lower() # Get question from user

  with open(Question_file, "w") as q:        # Create a new file with the question
                   q.write(Question.lower()) # in lowercase
                   q.close()                 # no need for close() here!

  with open(Answer_file, "r") as m:          # Read the answer file
    answer = m.read()                        # regardless of what's in it

  if 'hi' in Question:
     print ("hi")                            # Python 3 syntax?

  else:
    print answer                             # Python 2 syntax?
```

This will continue until you hit `Ctrl-C`.

Comment: I want it to overwrite and load the new answer everytime a question is asked

Comment: The problem is that Main.py only reads answer.txt once and stores that answer, I need it to constantly check for new answer

Comment: No, it reads answer.txt in every loop, and it doesn't store anything anywhere. hi.py is executed only once, and that's the only program that writes to answer.txt.

Comment: Is it possible to make hi.py run in loop?

Comment: `import`s are only run once. But you can move the code in hi.py into a function and call that several times. That also means that it will only execute when you call the function and not during the import itself. It seems you're struggling with some very basic Python concepts. Have you read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html), especially the part about importing modules?

Comment: I shall check it out.